# What are arguments for and against a bill "To end membership of the United States in the United Nations."

Tags: united-states, united-nations

[Here,](https://www.congress.gov/115/bills/hr193/BILLS-115hr193ih.pdf) one can see a bill "To end membership of the United States in the United Nations."

What do the proponents and opponents of the bill state to be advantages and disadvantages  of approval of the bill for the US?

Comment: Why the vote to close? This seems to be a real bill written by some real members of congress. It will very likely not pass, sure, but it may be discussed nevertheless.

Comment: Generally, asking for both pro- and con- arguments in the same Q is a bad idea. As you can see below, it turns out into a contest between them.

Comment: Stackexchange is not a debate forum. It is meant for questions with clear answers based largely on facts rather than opinions. Even a question that focuses on one of either "for" or "against" would still be far too opinion-based with no clear answer.

Answer (score 12):

Representative Mike Rodgers (Rep-Alabama), who introduced the bill, put out a [press release](https://mikerogers.house.gov/press-release/report-washington-restoring-and-protecting-american-sovereignty) explaining why he did it.  More generally, various people have called for less involvement with, or active rejection of, the UN; for instance, WND.com carries a [call for a petition](http://www.wnd.com/2016/12/is-it-time-to-defund-discount-deport-united-nations/) that reads in part,

> The United Nations has voted more times to condemn Israel, the shining light of democracy in the Middle East, than North Korea, the rogue communist regime. Or Somalia. Or Vietnam. In fact, more than all the other nations of the world combined.
>
> It also adopts procedures and policies to override national law and advocate for abortion.
>
> It routinely appoints nations with questionable records on human rights, such as Angola and Senegal, to its Security Council.
>
> It threatens Americans’ constitutional rights through its Arms Trade Treaty and even parental rights through its Convention on the Rights of the Child.
>
> But its latest condemnation of Israel, with the full acquiescence of the Barack Obama administration, is one step too far, charges a new petition that urges the U.S. Congress and incoming President Donald Trump to do something about the international institution.
>
> Such as defund it.
>
> And discount its decisions and pronouncements.
>
> And deport it.

In other words, proponents of such a bill presumably believe that defunding the UN would protect American sovereignty and morally cleanse them from indirectly supporting repressive governments; but the last straw was [Resolution 2334](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_2334), which is widely perceived as hostile to Israel.

I expect that there are a lot of arguments, some mutually contradictory, that different opponents would use against the bill. Some people (including some U.S. Citizens) might say that the U.S. ought to conform to the full corpus of modern international law, that it has a moral imperative to support the development of less-privileged societies, and that the U.N. resolution on Israel and Palestine is valid because Israel is a tool of white oppression.

Others might agree that some activities of the U.N. are troubling or ineffective, but also believe that overall the organization and the framework in which it operates does a lot of good; more of a "don't throw the baby out with the bathwater" argument.

There is a MoveOn [petition](http://petitions.moveon.org/sign/bill-to-remove-us-from?) against the bill; as of this writing it has only been signed by three people and the body is short enough that I can quote it verbatim,

> This bill is a pre-cursor to Ending the United Nations! This puts not only our country and family at stake but may end the planet.

Either way, an [article](http://www.thenewamerican.com/usnews/congress/item/21058-congressman-mike-rogers-introduces-bill-to-get-u-s-out-of-un) in The New American points out that similar bills have been introduced in previous congresses:

> By introducing the bill in this session, the congressman from Alabama continues the long and valiant effort by lawmakers to get the U.S. government out of the UN. Former Rep. Ron Paul (R-Texas), a GOP presidential candidate last election and a hero of many liberty-minded and constitutionalist Americans, first introduced the bill in 1997, when it garnered 54 supporters. The next time it was voted on, support had drastically increased.

Answer (score 5):

One of the largest arguments against the US leaving the UN is because of its status as one of the 5 permanent members of the UN Security Council. Should the US leave, it would lose veto power for proposals introduced by Russia and China, and as such would have to curry favour with France or Britain to veto the proposal.

This hurts American interests as it's unlikely that either Britain or France would change their minds about supporting a proposal unless the US gives them something in return.

Another argument against it would become blindingly obvious if you ever visit the UN and talk to one of the tour guides. Hundreds of thousands of meetings take place each year in the various UN buildings. They're one of the greatest tools of International diplomacy ever conceived. Should the US leave, it would have no standing or say in the meetings that take place, only allowed to offer an opinion that the rest of the UN are completely free to disregard entirely.

Comment: Yeah, as the USSR learned in the 1950s in the Korean war, "shunning the UN" doesn't work out too well in practice. It's more likely to be effective if several big countries leave, as it happened with its predecessor, the League of Nations.

Answer (score 0):

It's an "H.R.".  Meaning it's a "House Resolution".  As such, the bill would not have any power in law.
The domain of the foreign policy in the United States lies with the President of the United States, with advice and consent of the Senate.

The Constitution does not give the House of Representatives a role in shaping the foreign policy of the United States outside of its budgetary powers and the power to regulate commerce with foreign powers.

Comment: It does have the power to pass a bill that would be sent to the senate and if passed there sent to the president to sign into law or veto.

Comment: @JoeW but it has no power in law without the Senate passage.  In any case, it could be challenged (in court) on process because the House has no authority to initiate such sweeping diplomacy questions.

Comment: You mean like every other item that passes the house? I don't think anyone was suggesting that the house could vote to remove the US from the UN on their own. If it would have passed the house, the senate and gotten signed by the president (or had the veto overridden) it would have removed the US from the UN.

Comment: @JoeW no, you can't challenge every item on process, at least not credibly.  But when a house passes a bill initiating a foreign policy change, it can be challenged on process grounds because the House has no *blanket* authority to conduct foreign policy.

Comment: What evidence do you have to back up the claim that the house cannot pass a bill dealing with foreign policy and not send it on to the senate to pass? If you are going to answer a 7 year old question you should provide sources to back up your claims. Besides this question isn’t asking if they can do this but the arguments for and against doing it.

Comment: @JoeW no kidding!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151293/discussion-between-wrod-and-joe-w).

Comment: Sorry but there is nothing to continue in chat.

Comment: So you're saying that there *are* no advantages or disadvantages to the bill, because it's non-binding?

Comment: @F1Krazy the bill was showboating.  I don't think there is 1 instance in the history of the US when such an action succeeded because it would be blatantly unconstitutional. So its not a solid premise for a question.  I could also argue that the question itself is asking for opinions, but I guess it can be answered very narrowly if one is to limit themselves just to known facts.  But, in my estimate, such a narrow answer would likely attract downvotes from all the activists on the site. But that, too, is just an opinion; one I am not willing to test.

Comment: @wrod The Homeland Security Act originated in the House of Representatives, with obvious foreign policy impacts. While the House plays no role in the formation of treaties, terminating a treaty can originate in the House. Declaration of war must come from Congress and can originate in the House.

Comment: @DavidHammen The Homeland Security Act is not a foreign policy initiative. It creates tools for the executive, but they are executive branch's tools to use. re:"While the House plays no role in the formation of treaties." If you mean that it is the diplomats and the lawyers who draft it, that's (of course) irrelevant. They are the plumbers of the process. The signing (or not) of a treaty begins with the President's signature. If a President elects to not sign a treaty, there is no way to compel him. So the drafters' actions have no force of law. Any *actual* treaty termination started in HoR?